# hc-05 bluetooth disables serial port?

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I mean, can this be possible?

I have tried several times to upload normal projects to my arduino and works well. But when I upload a code related to the hc-05 (despite that i still haven't figured out how this module works after an entire day of trial-and-error, because it simply doesn't work) **it cuts the serial connection (ttyACM0) and it's impossible to upload any other project of any kind** to the arduino. The port is blocked and nothing i can do to unblock it (yeah i alreday surfed the web for solutions and none of them worked, i swear the only thing that has worked it's formatting the Ubuntu and re-installing it, which wasn't any drama due to my little data stored).

I am completely aware that formatting is not the solution and this sounds stupid, but i swear is what happens. It's just doing anything related with the Bluetooth module and the port is gone for transfering data via the Arduino IDE (plugging other things like mouse and pendrives still work).

Thanks for the help in advance. I'm desperate. Any hugs will be also appreciated.

**EDIT:** The problem that is face after this is, in the IDE:

Error at opening serial port '/dev/ttyACM0'.

**EDIT 2:** Here is the code. As mentioned in the comments, **now seems like the port only blocks when I change from 9600 to any other baud rate HIGHER (not 4800)**.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(38400);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  Serial.println("configuracion!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port

}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

**EDIT 3:** As said in the comments, the port ACM0 is **blocked "forever and ever" again**, even if I restart the computer. Could be that the port becomes "tired" of too many trials uploading sketches?

**EDIT 4:** As said in the comments, after running the arduino IDE in sudo mode

```
$ sudo arduino
```

it allows me to upload all the sketches I want, and doesn't seem to have any problems with the changings in the baud rate.

After all, **seems like is a permissions issue**, but i wonder how this went so big, and how permissions changed with a simple operation. Anyway, i can't make it work without sudo (I must say that I am already a member of the **dialout** group), so here we are by now (Exciting isn't it?).

---

**[SOLVED?]:** I've changed the baud rate by code, so where it was 38400, now its 9600 bauds:

```
  mySerial.begin(9600);
```

Seems like **my version of the HC-05 module (version zs-040) needs to work at 9600 bauds** for an effective entry to the AT mode and (for what i've seen) for working normally, although that in most websites you will see it works at 38400. Not for this version or I couldn't do the way the other people make it work at 38400.

In http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-with-hc-05-bluetooth-module-at-mode/ i've seen that this particular module has 4 ways for entering in the AT mode, but in my case only **the 4th method** that appears there has worked for me.

So here it is the *solution* if we can call it like that, change the baud rate established in the code to 9600 bauds. **No issues since i did that, everything working smoothly**.

Thanks @frarugi87 and @Fabricio for your comments, which have helped me on finding the correct way.

---

Comment: Ok, the HC-05 is a serial bluetooth adapter. So.. How did you connect it to the board?

Comment: Hi frarugi87, mine is a HC-05 version zs-040, which has the following pins:
State, rxd, txd, gnd, vcc, En. It also has a button for entering the AT mode

Comment: ok, now I can quote myself and ask "How did you connect it to the board?"

Comment: I connect all of them except the STATE and the EN. I use SoftwareSerial for communicating via serial, using pins 10 and 11 for rx and tx. The rest is what is supposed to be, with a tension divider for rx (also tried without it)

Comment: Ok. Now, does the problem arise when you upload a HC-05 related code or when you upload any code when the HC-05 is plugged in?

Comment: I will try the second one after formatting again, as the port is not responding now. I will respond in a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: Ok.. If it does not disappear when you upload a generic sketch (e.g. blink) with the HC-05 attached, try uploading a HC-05 sketch without attaching the HC-05 itself. If it does block the port, post the code

Comment: I've found what could be the root of the problem.

With the HC-05 attached, and also uploading a HC-05 sketch, nothing happened at first, everything seems to work despite that i couldn't send AT commands, as happened before the main problem discussed here.

BUT the problem araised again when i changed, in the IDE serial monitor, the baud rate at which i wanted to communicate via serial. When i changed it from 9600 to 38400 bauds and both NL&CR, in a few seconds the port blocked! It also appears the file LCK..ttyACM0 under /var/lock of course. 

I make a post edit including the code.

Comment: News: after closing and opening again the IDE, now the uploading works (unexpectedly). So now seems like it doesn't block forever.

Comment: Nothing said, it's **blocked again**, even if i restart the computer.

Could be that the serial becomes "tired" of the lots of trials in uploading that I do? I make EDIT 3.

Comment: Big news: I tried running the IDE in sudo mode

($ sudo arduino)

Now the uploading works. **It seems finally that is a permissions issue.** (i make EDIT 4). Anyway i can't make it work. I am already member of the dialout group.

Comment: this is really odd... Instead of the serial port I'd have a look at that lock file. Who is the owner?

Comment: Process with the id 5634. Should I kill it and see if it appears again? I guess there should be some linux command to know the id of all running processes

Comment: you can use `ps aux | grep 5634`, even if there should be a better command but this should work.. anyway., is the lock file owned by root or another user?

Comment: dani@ROS:~$ ls -l /var/lock ;;;;;;;;;;
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 abr  5 15:16 /var/lock -> /run/lock ;;;;;;;;;
dani@ROS:~$ ls -l /var/lock/LCK..ttyACM0 ;;;;;;;;;
-r--r--r-- 1 dani dani 11 abr  6 16:05 /var/lock/LCK..ttyACM0 ;;;;;;
dani@ROS:~$ ps aux | grep 2253 ;;;;;;;;
dani      2253  2.9  2.9 3256320 118684 ?      Sl   16:03   0:09 java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel processing.app.Base
dani      2759  0.0  0.0  15964  2236 pts/0    S+   16:08   0:00 grep --color=auto 2253 ;;;;

Comment: as you see, now the proceess is 2253, and as answers to who is the owner, seems I am the owner (i'm dani), although the owner of the folder is root (seems obvious)

Comment: This is really odd for me.. Sorry, I think it is a permission problem, but I can't understand how to solve it :( Try with Fabricio's edit and let me know what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

I noted that you are using Linux, please check that ACM0 has the rights user permissions.

To enable for read and write you should set the permissions for ACM0 or can also add you user to dialog group. I prefer to add the user to dialog group because it will persist on reboot:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout [youruser]
```

**Note:** Please take in account that you need to logout and login again to the group reflect the new user.

### Edit 1:

If your device is not in dialout group please run the next command:

```
sudo chgrp dialout /dev/[yourdevice]
```

This change will work until reboot, but it will help you to know if the issues come from group/user/device configuration.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks fabricio but another weird thing is that i am already member of the dialout group

Comment: Please @thepirate16 take a look at the **Edit 1**

Comment: It doesn't work @Fabricio ,i've run both commands and nothing happens